# Add second KPI to Qlik View distribution plot

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am using a distribution plot in qlik sense desktop

[image]

Right now I have a

- Dimension Point: Column A
- Y-axis: column B
- x-axis: column C

Right now I am only see the distribution of the x-axis in percentage, how can I add the absolute numbers to it?

how can I add another KPI to it that when I am moving over it with the mouse I also see another number ?

Comment: I was trying to solve it but both my ideas "Alternative meassure" and "Dual" function which I used in qlikview don't give help here. Have you managed to figure out something?

Comment: I think its the wrong visualiziaton for it